# Pandas drop duplicates where condition

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to `df.drop_duplicates()` based off a subset, but also ignore if a column has a specific value.

For example...

```
                 v1      v2     v3      
ID                                                          
148         8751704.0    G      dog   
123         9082007.0    G      dog  
123         9082007.0    G      dog 
123         9082007.0    G      cat
```

I would like to drop duplicate `[ID, v1]` but ignore if `v3` is equal to `cat` so something like this:

`full_df.drop_duplicates([ID, v1], inplace=True, conditional=exclude v3 = cat)`

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and [`pd.Index.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html):

```
df[~(df['v1'].duplicated() & df.index.duplicated()) | df['v3'].eq('cat')]
```

**Output**

```
            v1 v2   v3
ID                    
148  8751704.0  G  dog
123  9082007.0  G  dog
123  9082007.0  G  cat
```

if `ID`is not the index:

```
df[~df[['ID', 'v1']].duplicated() | df['v3'].eq('cat')]
```

Comment: When I try to run your second solution I get: `KeyError: ('ID', 'v1')`

Comment: Ahh yes, for speed, what would be the fastest solution in your opinion ?

Comment: if ID is the index I think this solution with `pd.Index.duplicated` is faster because you don't have to use `reset_index`. But I don't know because I haven't tested it with various sizes of DataFrame. 
anyway i think both solutions are good

Answer (score 6):

You could use chain another condition using a bitwise and, to ensure that `cat` is not `cat`:

```
df[~(df.reset_index().duplicated(['ID', 'v1']) & df.v3.ne('cat').values).values]

        v1     v2   v3
148  8751704.0  G  dog
123  9082007.0  G  dog
123  9082007.0  G  cat
```